# UITableView separators disappears?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

in my uitableview, i subclassed uitableviewcell's, and i added a subview to the contentview with flexible width and height. the cells are of dynamic height.

when the tableview first loads, everything is fine. however, as i start to scroll around, separators start disappearing, and they happen at the same places every launch. scrolling around some more will recover the lost separators.

anyone else encounter this?

Comment: what is the height of the `UITableViewCells`? or you adding Custom Cells?

Comment: they are all different. the contents do not overlap into other cells. everytime the tableview calls cellforindexpath, i feed uitableviewcell information and send it a setNeedsDisplay call to redraw.

Comment: as you said you have different heights; so try to +5 the dynamic heights you're feeding, would that happen at the same places?

Comment: i actually already do a +20 to my dynamic heights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was related to the dynamic heights. Using either ceilf or floorf solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how specific this will be to your project, but I'll tell you what I figured out. Overriding my `layoutSubviews` method was the problem. I looked at the view hierarchy of my cell before and after I called `[super layoutSubviews]` and discovered that this method was making the contentView 1 pixel shorter and added a new view below it 1 pixel high with a background color of 0.88/0.88/0.88.

If you can't live with some of the side effects of the superclass implementation, it looks like this view must be added manually.